# Exponential equation problem with no solution?

Tags: exponential-function

I have trouble solving this:

$$3^x+3^{2-x}=8$$

I have tried substituting $3^x=z$ but that doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Substituting $3^x=z$ ought to give you $z+9/z=8$. That looks quite helpful. Multiply that by $z$ and you have a quadratic equation.

Comment: I did get to the quadratic but I cant find $x$ after because I can't take the logarithm. I get a square root in the solution

Comment: It has 2 real solutions. This equation can be written as $9^x - 8\times 3^x + 9 = 0$ which is now a quadratic in $3^x$

Comment: @DenisDüsseldorf Assuming $\log (a+b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$, you are correct. Sadly, that's not the case.

Comment: You know, Double, you'd get much more helpful answers if you'd tell people in the first place how far you've gotten and where you get stuck.

Comment: @DoubleOseven: By "I can't take the logarithm" do you mean that the quadratic has no real roots, or only negative roots? If that is the case, the original equation has no (real) solutions. But in fact is has (unless I'm doing something wrong) two real roots.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mean I can't simplify the equation to get to the solution

Comment: @DoubleOseven: What does that mean? Which roots do you get for the quadratic?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let me just rewrite the equation for you

$$3^x + 3^{2-x} = 8\\
3^x + 3^2\cdot 3^{-x} = 8\\
3^x + 9\cdot (3^x)^{-1} = 8.$$

Now, try the substitution again. What do you get?

Comment: That is what I did but if you continue you will see that the solution can't be simplified. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DoubleOseven: When I continue there seems to be absolutely no problems with getting the two solutions for $x$. Instead of just continuing to assert that there is some problem that you're stuck at, you need to  **show exactly what point you're stuck at** instead of leaving it to the reader to _guess_ what you're doing.

Comment: @DoubleOseven Yes. Please write down the equation you get, and the solution.

Comment: @DoubleOseven Also, in future, please don't just say "that's not possible". Instead say "I tried this, got this far, now I don't know how to proceed". If you want good answers, **show your work**. That way, we can address the part that is troubling you directly.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $3^x$ to both sides: $3^{2x} + 9 = 8\cdot 3^x \implies 3^{2x} - 8\cdot 3^x + 9 = 0\implies (3^x - 4)^2 = 7 \implies 3^x - 4 = \pm \sqrt{7}\implies 3^x = 4 \pm \sqrt{7} \implies x = \log_{3}(4 \pm \sqrt{7})$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rewrite it as
$$
3^{2x} - 8\cdot3^x + 3^2 = 0
$$

given that $3^{-x} \ne 0$. Then, solving for $3^x$ gives you

$$
3^x = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 9}}{1}. 
$$

Comment: That is what I got too but how to do I get $x$?

Comment: $\log_b{b^x} = x \log_b{b} = x$

Comment: @DoubleOseven: Haven't you learned how to solve an equation of the form $a^x=b$? You solve it by taking the base-$a$ logarithm on both sides!